# Stable liquid pressure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure

How to obtain a constant pressure by a mini water pump to 9 bar?

Ex given a common engine for the aquarium, how to obtain at the output a pressure that is stable to 9 or 10 bar?

Comment: Can you give some more information? Do you mean the pump discharge pressure? Can you change what is downstream of the pump- for example, change the height or add a valve? What do you need to do with 9 bar water?

Comment: Espresso machine pressure, it sounds like...

Comment: yes, i would try to buil my homemade espresso machine

Comment: If you want consistent pressure, get a rotary pump that puts out as a minimum more than 9 bar then use a regulator.

Comment: 90m tall water tower. Use the tiny pump to drive a pulley with string with tiny buckets to fill it.

Comment: @SF. Practical.

Answer (score 0):

Use pneumatic pump (diapraghm or piston type) that has 1:1 pressure ratio. Feed the pump using compressed air that have pressure regulator set at 9 bar.